# meta viewport width not working in html file

Tags: html, viewport, meta-tags

I'm new to HTML trying to learn and sort things out now.
I learned about a meta tag and it's a data of the data.
I learned the concept of using device-width for various types of devices i.e mobile phones.

Here my the code that I wrote

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>question</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=100">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I intend my whole HTML `content=body` to be styled as width `100 px` since I wrote `viewport width 100`, but it didn't work on any device.

I thought no matter how big is my browser or the resolution of my monitor, the `p` text would be shown within `100 px` width but what I see is just resizable content which means the `p` contents are shown in full width of my browser.

I've searched about `viewport` tag and there was no such thing I've found what I'm looking for only I can assume is I'm lacking a JSON file to use the viewport attribute?

I would be really glad if someone can help me to understand this problem!
Thanks in advance and my knowledge background is just HTML and a bit of CSS since I've started to learn these a week ago .

Answer (score 0):

From MDN Docs you can see what it says:

> For pages that set an initial or maximum scale, this means the width
> property actually translates into a minimum viewport width.

Please refer to the below link to know more about it :)

[Viewport-And-Widths from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_width_and_screen_width)

Comment: hello thanks for the link the thing is i dont understand what are they saying . i guess due to my lack of knowledge can u explain more? so does it mean if i dont use initial scale attribute width doesnt work? thanks